# Flask - Cannot use instance celery into app/__init__.py?

Tags: python, flask, design-patterns, celery

I have already visited several questions in the community, but I believe this is my fault because I was unable to identify an adequate way, in the use of the factory architecture pattern indicate in [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/) Flask.

We have an application, based on ***Flask + Gunicorn + Nginx***, that always worked without major challenges. However, we need to build a solution that requires asynchronous tasks.
Soon the indication was unanimous, to use Celery for this, but even following the style used [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern/page/3#comments).

I can't make the project compile because it informs that there are import errors and the official [documentation of the framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/) does not bring much clarity on how to use it, in the structure factory, just how to do it in single instance.

How can I solve this?

**My traceback:**

```
  File "/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/celery_runner.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/app/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .api import configure as config_api
  File "/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/app/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .resources.chosen import Change
  File "/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/app/resources/chosen.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.jobs.tasks import exec_change as tk_change
  File "/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/app/jobs/tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'celery' from 'app' (/home/user/Workspace/test/project_async/app/__init__.py)
```

**My structure:**

```
.
├── app
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── celeryconfig.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── tasks.py
│   ├── jwt.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── inventory.py
│   │   └── other.py
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── chosen.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── schemas.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── chosen.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── chosen_other.py
│   │   └── inventory.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── swagger.json
│   │   └── swagger.yaml
│   ├── swagger.py
│   └── utils.py
├── celery_runner.py
├── config.py
├── main.py
├── test.log
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_inventory.py
```

**Code:**

**path - app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from config import configure as config_project

from .api import configure as config_api
from .jwt import configure as config_jwt
from .models.core import configure as config_db
from .models.inventory import configure as config_db_mongo
from .swagger import configure as config_docs
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__)

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    '''Added Configurations'''
    config_project(app)
    config_jwt(app)
    config_api(app)
    config_docs(app)
    config_db(app)
    config_db_mongo(app)
    '''Added Thirds'''
    CORS(app)
    Migrate(app, app.db)
    '''Background Tasks'''
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    celery.config_from_object('app.jobs.celeryconfig')

    return app
```

**path - project_async/celery_worker.py**

```
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv

from app import create_app

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

app = create_app(getenv('FLASK_ENV') or 'default')
app.app_context().push()
```

**path - app/jobs/celeryconfig.py**

```
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# import
imports = 'app.jobs.tasks'

# Timezone
timezone = 'America/Bogota'
enable_utc = True
```

**path - app/jobs/tasks.py**

```
from app import celery
from app.services.chosen_other import ChangeOpportunity


@celery.task(name='tasks.change')
def exec_change(data, change, client):
    change = ChangeOpportunity(data, change, client)
    change.execute_change()
```

Comment: Looks to me like you simply have circular imports. One module is importing another which is importing another which is ultimately importing the first one again.

Comment: That's right @deceze , I had already discovered this, the error is in the way I call the instance of celery in `app/__ init__.py` inside the module `app /jobs/tasks.py`. But how to solve this?

Comment: Mostly by not putting a whole lot of things into an `__init__.py`. Put all that into explicit submodules and import from those explicitly.

Comment: However @deceze, in several styles of projects, using flask, I notice that injecting external configurations, such as contexts for the database, among others, is functional. Apparently just with celery this doesn't seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by circular imports. The actual problem is that importing `api.py` ends up importing your Celery tasks. Since you are doing the `from .api import configure` before you define the `celery` instance, this breaks with the circular dependency.

You should try to reorganize your code so that doing an import of one module does not require a lot of other modules to be imported. If you look at your stack trace you can see that `api.py` imports `resources/chosen.py`, which imports `jobs/tasks.py`. Is all the cross package importing necessary?

Try breaking up your more complex modules so that you don't have all these indirect imports.